# Correct headers for PHP RESTful Application?

Tags: php, rest, restful-authentication

**Goal:** A RESTful API
**Question:** Is the method I have below a true RESTful API or is it missing something like I was told?
 This is a 3 part question..

Let's assume I have a PHP project that has an API that returns data in either XML or JSON formats, you would access the API like this below...

```
server.com/article/123 | Returns ID 123 using GET
server.com/article/new | Creates a new article using POST
server.com/article/123/edit | Edits an article with the ID 123 using POST
server.com/article/123/delete | Deletes article with ID 123 using POST
```

**1)**
I always read also that `PUT` should be used for editing objects, below I put the word `POST` as the user would send a `POST` to tht URI for the delete action, should I be using `PUT` in php by using something like this instead?

```
$_PUT  = array();  
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {  
    parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $_PUT);  
}
```

**2)**
I was told in a question I wrote on SO a while back that this is similar to a RESTful API but that it is not, the answer I got was this...

`In short, your service is not RESTful, but it is close. Rather than specify actions (edit, delete, ...) in URL segments, you will want to make use of HTTP verbs (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE).`

Either the guy did not know what he was talking about or I just DO NOT GET IT, after reading countless articles on the subject, and comparing with every API I can find, how is my example above NOT RESTful?

I would like to make a RESTful API, please help me correct my example above if needed?

**3)**
Also assuming I plan returning a JSON response to the user with something like this...

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');  
header('Content-type: application/json');

$data = // my code that returns the appropriate data;

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Is that the correct way of returning the result to a user or am I missing something? 
 Many articles and questions talk about the concept but don't get into the actual code like my examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To address part 2 of your question, a more RESTful URL and method structure would be as follows:

- `server.com/articles/123` – `GET`: return the article
- `server.com/articles/123` – `PUT`: replace the article with the one in the request body
- `server.com/articles/123` – `DELETE`: delete the article
- `server.com/articles/` – `POST`: create a new article

The idea here is that the URL represents the resource itself (in this case, the article) and the verb, where practical, indicates what you want to do to it. The best example I can think of in the wild of a *true* RESTful API is the latest version of the [GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/): as far as I have seen, they use HTTP methods, response codes and custom MIME types appropriately.

In answer to part 3 of your question, that is certainly a valid way to do it, but if you were to use a custom MIME type such as `application/vnd.myawesomesite.article+json`, that would make it easier to interpret at the client’s end, as the client could use the MIME type to determine how to parse the result: for instance, the client could dispatch to different deserialisers and classes depending on the MIME type presented. Again, the folks at GitHub give some examples in [their API docs](http://developer.github.com/v3/mime/).

Comment: thanks I will check out the mime types and the github api, also that was one of the better explanations.  The 1 thing I am still not certain of is the `PUT` I'f I were accessing this API with PHP, how would I sent a `PUT` request is what I am not sure of.  Next thing on my list is Aunthentication with something like OAuth, If I am sending `GET` to `server.com/articles/123` then I am not sure how pass in any authentication unless maybe it is sent using `GET` as well but i'm sure these deserve there own question

Answer (score 2):

1. You should be able to use `$_POST` on a PUT request, as long as the request includes a the proper Content-Type header. It's a generic superglobal that should always be filled when there is a HTTP body sent and the correct Content-Type header is used. In fact, it could even appear on a broken GET request.
2. Your URLs could be more RESTful. For example, `server.com/article/123` could house not only GET, but also POST (edit) and DELETE (delete). There's no need to use separate URLs if you're already using different request methods.
3. RESTful primarily describes the way of communicating between the client and the server, not how it does that. I haven't seen the 201 header used much in the past - usually a `200 OK` is good enough. Of course, nothing should stop you from using the 201 code.

#protip: wrap all your data in a result object, like `{'success':true,'result':<the result>,'resulttype':'article'}`. Developers using your API (if you publish one) will find this helpful. For you this means that you can add extra information to the response easily.

[Very interesting article on FourSquare's REST API](http://engineering.foursquare.com/2011/07/08/apiv2-woulda-coulda-shoulda/)

Comment: I'm not sure I would find that helpful. You should use the status code and response headers to supply meta data (such as whether the request was successful), not the response body.

Comment: @JohannesGorset While I agree, developers will always prefer having this information in the response body as well, since it's easier for development without compromising anything. Of course, make sure to *also* send HTTP response codes.

Comment: On the contrary! I would argue that it makes development more difficult to require clients to parse arbitrary data from the response body to sift information they already have.

Comment: Why? If you don't want the info, simply start reading at the `result` part of the response instead of the root. That hardly takes any extra code, while developers using certain modern platforms (javascript being one of them) will consider it to be very helpful if there's an easy way to access error information.

Comment: I see what you mean about using 1 uri for GET, POST, and PUT and the 201 was supposed to be 200 so I changed it above, thanks for all the input

Comment: @jasondavis 200 is OK, not Created. That's 201.

Comment: Also you put `1) as long as the request includes a the proper Content-Type header` does that mean for an edit, in the request that is sent using `POST` they should include a header of `PUT` ?

Comment: What I meant is that `$_GET` and `$_POST` are misleading - they should be called `$_QUERY` and `$_BODY` — `$_POST` will always be filled if it can find the right data, independent of the request method. If the data you post (or put) has the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type header, PHP will interpret it properly.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt: How is it easier to parse meta data from the response body than its status code and headers?

Comment: 1. More data fits in the body than a response header. 2. In most programming languages you'll have to parse the body anyway so you'll already have a parser and the body ready. 3. There are popular programming frameworks (jQuery, for example) that give you easier access to the body than the headers. 4. Good luck putting an array of errors in a header, compared to the JSON equivalent. And in cases where you don't need any of this error data you can simply look for the status code (2xx or 4xx/5xx) and start parsing @ result.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt: I'm not sure you understand. I'm not suggesting that you use headers to communicate errors. If a request produced an error, a server that adhered to REST would respond with a status code in the range of 400-600 and a request body with a more specific description of why things went awry...

Comment: That's what I am saying as well... However, I would always wrap the response in an envelope that is always the same, error or no error. This would include a `success` (true/false) boolean plus, if applicable, a list of errors. Of course I would also send the status codes.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt: I can see how that might be advantageous, though I like to think of the response body as a representation of the requested resource and meta data like 'success' and 'resulttype' have no part in it. It's also worth noting that you'd be hard pressed to convey these things in the response body if it's represented in a simpler format (say, CSV), and that would lead to ambiguity in your service.